# How To Figure Out Repeat Purchase Rate With Multiple Variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in an excel sheet that is essentially a list of all orders for my company over its life span (approximately 14 thousand orders if it matters.) The following fields are relevant for what I'm trying to do currently.

```
Purchase date (i.e. 6/23/19)
```

Customer ID (unique ID given to each customer, this ID is constant across all of a customers purchases)

```
Product category (widgets, woozits, etc.)

Sales person (John Doe, Jane Doe, etc.)
```

What I'm trying to figure out is our repeat purchase rate by category, and then by sales person.

So ideally I'd like to be able to determine something like

```
Product category: Widgets
```

20% of people whose first purchase from us is a widget, purchased something else later on

Of widgets sold by John Doe to first time customers, 15% of the customers purchased something else from us later on

Of widgets sold by Jane Doe to first time customers, 25% of customers purchased something else from us later on.

So basically trying to figure out if different sales reps have better repeat purchase rates on their orders, however we must divide this by product category as our repeat purchase rate by category is going to vary widely (and some sales reps only sell items from certain categories so it would be unfair to compare across categories.)

I believe to do this I need to figure out how to say something like

"Find every widget John Doe sold ; see how many have customer ID's that did not appear on an earlier date ; then see what % of those customer ID's appear at a later date regardless of the next product category or sales person they purchased from."

Hopefully someone can help. I apologize if I didn't explain something particularly well, if there's any confusion I can try my best to clarify.

Thank you!

Comment: The queries you're describing are better suited to a database than a spreadsheet. Can you export your data to a sql database (mysql, sqlite, etc.) and then run your queries?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not at this time. Was hoping this could be accomplished in excel, even if in a complicated manner.

Comment: Could you provide sample input data and desired output? Doesn't have to be real from your DB, just something so I can make sure to understand what you're after.